# How to trim text on each line, starting with the first space

Tags: text-editing, column, deletion

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1

Suppose I has text:

```
Advertisment    d184f52a-14d7-dddddddddd

ZAnelik 1c970d12-6c67-44e1-cccccccccccc

Avers   b0f0dd6b-a43f-4e40-b0ebbbbbbbbb

BAVERS_MIGOM_OLD    473aaaaaaaaaaa5a-b6df-d5d38327e4ed
```

I need to extract text in the first column.
So result must be

```
Advertisment

ZAnelik

Avers

BAVERS_MIGOM_OLD
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `C-M-%` (`query-replace-regexp`) to delete text matching the pattern `" .*$"`. i.e., everything, starting with whitespace, up to the end of the line.